# audio video programming in C , linux

Tags: c, audio, video-processing

I want to learn ffmpeg, to implement file format conversion and player in C language under fedora linux. Where I can get the basic details of how audio video files are played in PC? 
Where I can get the best material for audio video programming?

Answer (score 2):

On http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ you find a very nice introduction to the ffmpeg c-api

Answer (score 2):

Start by watching that : http://xiph.org/video/vid1.shtml
You will need digital signal processing background : http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm
Alsa programming : http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735
For video display you can use SDL as explained by Friedrich.